# What are the consequences of removing covariance of random effects in multi-level models for model reliability?

Tags: mixed-model, covariance, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to asses the impact of cross-level effect on a dependent first-level variable. The problem I am facing is that the model returns singular fit. Some sources (https://www.learn-mlms.com/07-module-7.html) recommend to just remove random effects covariance. And it works. However, I wonder how it can impact the credibility of the model results and whether it is better to try some other methods such as using Bayesian calculation.